# Passing Variables to Nunjucks to be used in React

Tags: reactjs, jwt, csrf, csrf-protection, nunjucks

Using React, Node, and Express, with a single Nunjucks page for a template, I'm trying to pass a jwt-csrf token from my express server to the Nunjucks page as a javascript variable to be used in the React front-end (which will create post requests with the token).

This is the code in the njk template:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% include "partials/head.njk" %}
    <title>{{appname}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"/>
    <script src="/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I had the idea of adding an additional script tag with a global variable, something like like:

```
<script>window.token = {{token}}</script>
```

but the `{{` and `}}` get interpreted as javascript rather than as a nunjucks variable.  How do I use nunjucks inside of Javscript?

Also, please let me know if what I'm doing is super not-secure, heh.

Comment: You can create a hidden input and set it's value through Nunjucks. Then, your script tag can look up that input, grab the value and set `window.token`.

Comment: That would do it.  Thanks!